# jQuery: Position of Images inside a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a table:

```
  <table id="table1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td id='id1'  style="width:200px"></td>
      <td id='id2'  style="width:200px">2222</td> 
    </tr>

  </table>
```

I am using following code to add images to these table cells

```
$('#id1').append('<img src=images/image1.jpg />');
$('#id1').append('<img src=images/image2.jpg />');
$('#id1').append('<img src=images/image3.jpg />');

$('#id2').append('<img src=images/image4.jpg />');
```

Now what I want to achieve is this:
1. for cell "id2", i want the image always align to the right so it's not next to the text. 
2. for cell "id1", since those 3 images has different sizes (24x24, 32x32, 24x24), i don't want them to be next to each other. what I want is that as if there are 3 small cells in that cell, each with size 32x32, and put those images into those small cells one by one.

I am not good at html or javascript. is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS

```
#id2 img { float: right; }
```

HTML

```
    <table id="table1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td id='id1'  style="width:200px"><table><tr></tr></table></td>
      <td id='id2'  style="width:200px">2222</td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Javascript

```
$('#id1').find('tr').append('<td><img src=images/image1.jpg /></td>');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off item #2 I'd say you're not done defining your table.  You need to add a nested table in #id2 (the merits of this approach can be debated later).

So your table would be

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="id1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="id1a"></td>
                    <td id="id1b"></td>
                    <td id="id1c"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

From there you'd append your images to the sub-cells.

Comment: Oswaldo Acauan beat me to it.  :)